# CSS image swapping; will not display correctly

Tags: html, css, image, background-image, swap

I am trying to add a hover image swap to my website gallery. Below is the CSS code I currently have. The original images that are in my HTML file display properly but the images are not switching when I hover over them.

CSS:

```
#gallery img {
    max-height: 25%;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    float: right;
    border-radius: 17px 0 17px 0;
    border:2px solid #888888;   
    background-image: url(/images/ferrari.jpg);
    background-image: url(/images/dalmation.jpg);
    background-image: url(/images/hanauma.jpg);
    background-image: url(/images/aircraft-sunset.jpg);
    background-image: url(/images/crab.jpg);
    background-image: url(/images/moth.jpg);
    background-image: url(/images/lake.jpg);
    background-image: url(/images/flag.jpg);
    background-image: url(/images/aircraft-landing.jpg);
    background-image: url(/images/tarantula.jpg);
    display: block;
}

#gallery img :hover {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

------------------>HTML

```
    <ul id="gallery"> 
    <li><img src="/images/ferrari-gray.jpg" alt=""/></li>
    <li><img src="/images/dalmation-gray.jpg" alt=""/></li>
    <li><img src="/images/hanauma-gray.jpg" alt=""/></li>
    <li><img src="/images/aircraft-sunset-gray.jpg" alt=""/></li>
    <li><img src="/images/crab-gray.jpg" alt=""/></li>
    <li><img src="/images/moth-gray.jpg" alt=""/></li>
    <li><img src="/images/lake-gray.jpg" alt=""/></li>
    <li><img src="/images/flag-gray.jpg" alt=""/></li>
    <li><img src="/images/aircraft-landing.jpg" alt=""/></li>
    <li><img src="/images/tarantula.jpg" alt=""/> </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you trying to have it so that when you hover over the image, it will scroll between all those background images? That's not how CSS works.

Comment: This requires javascript or a CSS animation for sure

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well.

Comment: i have 10 images total in my gallery that i want to display in grayscale then switch to the color versions once i hover over them.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use a `@keyframes` animation to do this, though it will have no transition without using some tricks with other elements or pseudo-elements and opacity

```
@keyframes changeImage {
    0%   { background-image: url(/images/tarantula.jpg); }
    10%  { background-image: url(/images/aircraft-landing.jpg); }
    20%  { background-image: url(/images/flag.jpg); }
    30%  { background-image: url(/images/lake.jpg); }
    40%  { background-image: url(/images/moth.jpg); }
    50%  { background-image: url(/images/crab.jpg); }
    60%  { background-image: url(/images/aircraft-sunset.jpg); }
    70%  { background-image: url(/images/hanauma.jpg); }
    80%  { background-image: url(/images/dalmation.jpg); }
    90%  { background-image: url(/images/ferrari.jpg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes changeImage {
    0%   { background-image: url(/images/tarantula.jpg); }
    10%  { background-image: url(/images/aircraft-landing.jpg); }
    20%  { background-image: url(/images/flag.jpg); }
    30%  { background-image: url(/images/lake.jpg); }
    40%  { background-image: url(/images/moth.jpg); }
    50%  { background-image: url(/images/crab.jpg); }
    60%  { background-image: url(/images/aircraft-sunset.jpg); }
    70%  { background-image: url(/images/hanauma.jpg); }
    80%  { background-image: url(/images/dalmation.jpg); }
    90%  { background-image: url(/images/ferrari.jpg); }
}
```

The only other option (likely the better one) is to use javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a space between:

```
img  :hover
```

It has to be:

```
img:hover
```

I don't know what the multiple background images are about.

Comment: i have 10 images total in my gallery that i want to display in grayscale then switch to the color versions once i hover over them. At least that is what i am trying to accomplish. Very new to coding but i do know that webkits arent supported by all browsers so i was trying to avoid that route.

Comment: this is a similar style i am attempting to get close to
http://www.hexeract.org/101412/portfolio

Comment: CSS can't know which background image you want assigned to which img element.